# Gene and Protein isoform

Tags: proteins, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, isoforms

What is the relationship between term "Gene isoform" and "Protein isoform"?

Say a gene can make 3 isoforms, will it produce only (maximum) 3 isoform protein?

Comment: where are you seeing these terms - context will help answers

Answer (score 3):

The term isoform has become a little ambiguous over the years (see http://blogs.cornell.edu/collinslab/2012/05/30/protein-isoform/)... still some things are consistent:

- In some genetics literature 'isoform' has been used in the place of [allele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) when talking about the allele states at a locus for a gene
- Typically a [gene isoform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_isoform) is equivalent an alternate transcript. The gene isoforms are the set of mRNAs that can be produced by a gene.
- [Protein isoform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_isoform) commonly refers to the set of proteins produced by a gene, this can include variations produced by alternative splicing and post-translational modification. Note that in some contexts the set of products from closely related gene duplications can also be included.

Note that databases will typically have a specific definition in mind for their use of isoform in their annotation, check their documentation for details (e.g. in UniProt see [What is the canonical sequence? Are all isoforms described in one entry?](http://www.uniprot.org/help/canonical_and_isoforms))